# wordpress tinymce inserts &nbsp; instead of <br>

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

When I edit text in tinymce and press `enter` it inserts `&nbsp;` instead of `<br>`. Can you please advise how to force it insert new lines?

Comment: Please refer [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:force_br_newlines) it may help you

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you, the link located [HERE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-force-line-breaks-in-post#post-289814)